# How do I create a button that enters a string into a form using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I am a Rails Noob so I apologize if this is elementary. I'm creating a Twitter-like application and working on a 'reply' button that will automatically place a variable (the username of the tweet's author) into the tweet form at the top of the page. This is what I have now:

```
def reply
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
    @message = User.find_by_user_id(params[@tweet])
  end
```

I know that I'll have to change my routes but that's what I'm hung up on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. I'm, again, a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of code finds Tweet object. Then you put that tweet object into params hash as a key (this is the error). And AFAIK - you'd want to look into javascript that sets value for hidden field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how would I set this up in Java?

Comment: Java != Javascript. Try googling for "form manipulation with javascript".

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
def reply
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  @message = @tweet.user.username
end
```

It assumes that the `Tweet` model has an association called `user` and that your `User` model has an attribute `username`:

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tweets
  ...
end
```

And this would probably match the current behaviour of twitter a bit better:

```
def reply
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  @message = "@" + @tweet.user.username + " "
end
```

Comment: Hey tomas, thanks for your reply. I get an 'Unknown action' response when I use this code.  "No action responded to 160. Actions: create, current_user, current_user_flit?, destroy, logged_in?, login_required, redirect_to_target_or_default, and show" Any thoughts on how to correct? thanks.

Comment: What URL caused this? And how does your routes.rb file look like?